# Perl crash: Wrong use of glob in threads?

Tags: multithreading, perl, glob

The following script crashes in perl 5.16. Is there anything wrong with using `glob()` in threads?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use threads; 

sub f { 
    my $no = shift; 
    my @arr = glob("*"); 
    say "thread $no: ", scalar(@arr); 
} 

foreach my $tno (1..5) { 
    my $thr = threads->create(\&f, $tno); 
    $thr->join(); 
}
```

It prints

```
thread 1: 33
```

and then crashes with a segmentation fault (MacOS) or access violation (Windows 7).
Tested with `v5.16.2 on Mac OSX (darwin-thread-multi-2level)` and `ActivePerl on Windows 7 64bit (v5.16.3 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a [bug in perl](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=117823), I has been [fixed](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/facf34ef484d62d15b2da11ee03d01942a22ff15) in [5.18.2](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/perl-5.19.11/pod/perl5182delta.pod#___top).

Comment: Reference? Link to bug ticket?

Comment: Can't check it right now, but the bug doesn't seem to happen with v5.10.